# Множественное число в предложении

Tags: множественное-число

*Министерство имущественных и земельных отношений и Министерство курортов и туризма РК закончило инвентаризацию крымских пляжей.* Или "закончилИ"?

Answer (score 2):

Министерство имущественных и земельных отношений и Министерство курортов и туризма РК **закончили** инвентаризацию крымских пляжей.

Здесь препозиция двух однородных подлежащих определяет мн. число сказуемого.

Answer (score 2):

Два министерства-то. И порядок слов прямой. Стало быть, *закончил**и***.

Другие случаи можно посмотреть в:

[**§ 190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими**](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1015483/236/Rozental_-_Spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu,_proiznosheniyu,_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu.html)

Цитирую фрагмент параграфа:

> 1. При прямом порядке слов (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма множественного числа
>      сказуемого, при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) —
>      форма единственного числа.
>
> Например:
>
> а) *Жара и засуха стояли более трех недель* (Л. Толстой);
>
> б) *До Райского и Марфиньки долетел грубый говор, грубый смех,
>   смешанные голоса, внезапно притихшие…* (Гончаров); *Появилась ломота
>   во всех членах и мучительная головная боль* (Тургенев); *Несся тяжелый
>   топот кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи взвизги…* (Серафимович); *По
>   земле, истомленной в зное, разливалась свежесть, прохлада и
>   неизъяснимая легкость…* (В. Солоухин).
>
> Указанные положения не носят категорического характера, постпозитивное
>   сказуемое может стоять в форме единственного, а препозитивное — в
>   форме множественного числа (особенно часто в технической литературе).
>
> Форма множественного числа препозитивного сказуемого подчеркивает
>   множественность предметов,
>
> например:
>
> *Слышатся кашель и стук* (Чехов); *Снаружи были слышны визг, лай и вой* (Арсеньев). Обычно такая форма согласования бывает, когда
>   подлежащие обозначают лиц, например: *…Арестованы Букин, Самойлов,
>   Сомов и еще пятеро* (Горький). Но если сказуемое выражено глаголом
>   бытия или состояния, то оно может ставиться в форме единственного
>   числа, например: *Кроме нее, в комнате находился ее муж да еще некто
>   Увар Иванович Стахов…* (Тургенев) (влияет присоединительный характер
>   второго подлежащего).

Answer (score 1):

Можно свести это предложение к более очевидной форме "сидел**и** на трубе":

> Министерство А и министерство Б закончил**и** инвентаризацию.

И лишь в фантастическом случае, когда названия министерств используются как единое наименование, получается единственнное число:

> АО "Министерство А и министерство Б" закончил**о** инвентаризацию.